# $E(XY) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}8x^{2}y^{2}dx dy = \frac{4}{9}$

Tags: integration

$$E(XY) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}8x^{2}y^{2}dx dy = \frac{4}{9}$$

Can someone explain to me how the answer is 
$\frac{4}{9}$?

Comment: I tried to write the Equation not sure why it didn't work :(

Comment: Please add more detail. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need to put the equations between \$ ....... \$.

Comment: What you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(XY) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}8x^{2}y^{2}dx dy = \int_{0}^{1}[\frac{8}{3}x^3y^2]_y^1 dy = \int_{0}^{1}[\frac{8}{3}y^2-\frac{8}{3}y^5]dy=[\frac{8}{9}y^3-\frac{4}{9}y^6]_0^1=\frac{8}{9}-\frac{4}{9}=\frac{4}{9}$

So first you integrate with respect to x and use the inner limits, then integrate the result with respect to y and use the outer limits.

Comment: You are the best. Thank you